# Wanted: photo gallery with auto thumbnail generation

Tags: umbraco

I am looking for an Umbraco photo gallery, which supports automatic thumbnail generation (and possiblly other features), and ideally has source code, and can be integrated with uBlogsy.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three options from the package repository:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/simple-image-gallery-macro

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/jqgallery

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/easymodules-gallery